# Decoding HTTP GET parameter in Wireshark

Tags: windows, networking, http, wireshark, url

I am capturing HTTP GET traffic with Wireshark and I have plenty of URLs that contain "cryptic" URL-encoded data.

I'd like to

- see the URI split into the individual parameters
- see the parameter values in plain text

Example:
Today I see in Wireshark:

```
GET /index.xml?MODE=%40&MAC=63%3AA8%3A42%3AC0%3AE0%3AFD
```

And I'd like to see something like

```
MODE=@
MAC=63:A8:42:C0:E0:FD
```

How is that possible in Wireshark?

I have tried

- expanding the `GET` part in Wireshark
- right-clicking, decode as...

I know how to decode the URL e.g. with MIME-tools in Notepad++ or in online decoders, but I'd not like to do this for dozens of URLs.

Comment: Wireshark cannot do this automatically, as it doesn't actually know that that value is a url fragment, let alone that it's partially hex expressing UFT-8.

Comment: @FrankThomas: thanks for the comment. The format of a HTTP GET request is specified. So it would theoretically be possible to implement in Wireshark, but nobody has done so yet. Is that a correct hypothesis? If so, maybe I can add a feature request to Wireshark Bugzilla.

Comment: I'm sure its possible, but it would not necessarilly be desirable for all cases, so yeah, submit a feature request, and see if the devs (who know exactly what the constraints are), like it.